# " Exception from HRESULT: 0x8107054A " when activating wsp on Office365 Sandbox Solution

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, office-365, sandbox-solution, application-pages

I am uploading my wsp file and when I am trying to activate it getting this error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8107054A
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Flag in the VS Project Solution Properties of "Include Assembly in Package" set?

Comment: Yes, "Include Assembly in Package" = True

Comment: Office 365 doesn't support sandbox solutions with code in them anymore.

Comment: I have tried with "Include Assembly in Package" = False,.. then it shows error : 'Sandbox Code Execution Request Failed'. Not Working. What I have to do ??

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 does not support sandbox solutions that run .net code as Wictor's blog post orients you. Those were deprecated deprecated a year or two after he wrote it.

If you have anything running .net code on there, you're not going to be able to put it in Office 365. you need to move to the new App Model.

The Office Team have a [Github repository](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) with patterns and practices to help you shape your solution using the new model.

Depending on what you are attempting to do with code, someone might have an answer for you here on how to best achieve it on Office 365.